# Kafka Consumer max.poll.records vs Multiple partitions

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Wanted to understand about behavior of max.poll.records with Kafka topic with multiple partitions.
Suppose I have 8 partitions and 8 consumer instances in a single consumer-group. Suppose the producer produces 2000 messages at a very quick rate. Assume the use of round-robin partioner. And a very small message size (i.e. ignore fetch.max.bytes)

1. In an ideal case, will 250 messages be written to each of the 8 partitions?
2. If the max.poll.records at consumer level is default - 500 - then will each consumer instance pull all 250 records in one fetch?
3. Will Consumer instance 1 get Message 1, 9, 17, 25 etc?

Need to understand purely theoretically - in practice there are a lot of other variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick Answer - Yes to all your questions. I will explain in detail about your scenario so that the YES is justified. In your example:

- There is a Topic `T1` with 8 partitions.
- Consumer group of 8 consumers read from the topic -> each consumer
  gets assigned 1 partition
- Number of messages: 2000 (m1,m2,m3,...., m2000)
- Round Robin Partitioner

Assuming the messages are produced almost immediately (before any messages are consumed, the table shows how the messages are distributed in the kafka topic - each partition has 250 messages (**point1**).

```
Topic   | Partition | Messages
T1      |   P1      |   m1, m9,  m17, ..., m1993
T1      |   P2      |   m2, m10, m18, ..., m1994
T1      |   P3      |   m3, m11, m19, ..., m1995
T1      |   P4      |   m4, m12, m20, ..., m1996
T1      |   P5      |   m5, m13, m21, ..., m1997
T1      |   P6      |   m6, m14, m22, ..., m1998
T1      |   P7      |   m7, m15, m23, ..., m1999
T1      |   P8      |   m8, m16, m24, ..., m2000
```

Since each consumer of the consumer group is assigned only one partition, it will read upto 500 records like you mentioned. However since only 250 are available, the consumer reads 250 records/messages (**point2**)(Assumption: there are no other settings that could limit the number of messages read by kafka consumer and no more messages are written post initial write)

There is no gurantee around what consumer instance gets which partition assigned, but whichever consumer instance gets partition1 assigned will read messages m1,m9,m17,...,m1993 (**point3**)